# pull a git folder instead of the entire tree

Tags: git

Is it possible to pull/clone only **one folder** from a git repository instead of of the whole structure?

Comment: There have been some recent (2010 August–September) RFC patch series and discussions on the Git mailing list concerning partial/subtree/sparse/narrow cloning, so you may be able to in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can only clone a whole repository.

Answer (score 3):

As said, you can only clone repositories as a whole, and not parts of them.  If you need to, you might have put different projects into a single repository.  This is good in subversion, but not recommendable in Git.  If this is the case, split your repository into multiple repositories (one for each project), and aggregate these repositories in a central one using `git submodule`.